# Javascript Rock-Paper-Scissors game

Tags: javascript, html

I'm attempting a Rock-Paper-Scissors game in Javascript.  I am using 3 images as buttons in an HTML file.  I have run into an issue with the function that I am using to check for a win.  Each time I click a button, I get different values for the player selection, and computer selection, but only get the last value in the compare function when the two are compared.  For example, when I click "Rock", the computer will select "Paper" - but Javascript will read that we both selected "Scissors"(the last value in my compare function).  Any suggestions?

```
/*  SET ALL VARIABLES   */
//set choice variables
var p1Choice;
var p2Choice;
var cChoice;

//set the rock image to act as a button
function rockSelected (p1Choice) {
    p1Choice = "R";
    alert (p1Choice);
}

//set the paper image to act as a button
function paperSelected (p1Choice) {
    p1Choice = "P";
    alert (p1Choice);
}

//set the scissor image to act as a button
function scissorSelected (p1Choice) {
    p1Choice = "S";
    alert (p1Choice);
}

function cpuSelect (cChoice) {
    cChoice = Math.random();
    if (cChoice <= 0.33) {
        cChoice = "R"
        alert (cChoice)}
    else if (cChoice >= 0.34  && cChoice <= 0.66)
    {cChoice = "P";
    alert (cChoice);}
    else 
    {cChoice = "S";
    alert (cChoice);}
}

//check user imput against computer selection
function  compare (p1Choice, cChoice) {
    if (p1Choice == "R") {
        if (cChoice == "R") {
            alert ("player chose rock, cpu chose rock - it was a tie");
            return "it was a tie";
        }
        else if (cChoice == "P") {
            alert ("player chose rock, cpu chose paper - Paper wins!");
            return "paper wins";
        }
        else {
            alert ("player chose rock, cpu chose scissors - rock wins");
            return "rock wins";
        }
    }
    else if (p1Choice == "P") {
        if (cChoice == "R") {
            alert ("player chose paper, cpu chose rock - paper wins");
            return "paper wins";
        } else if (cChoice == "P") {
            alert ("player chose paper, cpu chose paper - it was a tie");
            return "it was a tie";
        } else {
            alert ("player chose paper, cpu chose scissors -scissors wins");
            return "scissors wins";
        }
    }
    else {
        if (cChoice == "R") {
        alert ("player chose scissors, cpu chose rock - rock wins");
        return "rock wins";
        } else if (cChoice == "P") {
            alert ("player chose scissors, cpu chose paper - scissors wins");
            return "scissors wins";
        } else {
            alert ("player chose scissors, cpu chose scissors - it was a tie");
            return "it was a tie";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you ever call `compare()`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I prevent console from printing in JavaScript game?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29936405/how-can-i-prevent-console-from-printing-in-javascript-game)

Comment: On a side note, your code formatting is no bueno (and completely inconsistent). You should follow a style guide, e.g., https://github.com/airbnb/javascript

Comment: I called the compare function on the buttons in the HTML file.<div class = "p1Rock"><img src = "rockButton.png" "100px" height = "100px" onclick = "rockSelected(p1Choice); cpuSelect(cChoice); compare(p1Choice, cChoice)"/></div>
<div class = "p1Paper"><img src = "paperButton.png" width = "100px" height = "100px" onclick = "paperSelected(p1Choice); cpuSelect(cChoice); compare(p1Choice, cChoice)"/></div>
<div class = "p1Scissor"><img src = "scissorButton.png" width = "100px" height = "100px" onclick = "scissorSelected(p1Choice); cpuSelect(cChoice); compare (p1Choice, cChoice)"/></

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do something really simple for this by doing a little circular assignment:

```
var choices = {
    rock: {},
    paper: {},
    scissors: {}
};

choices['rock'].beats = choices['scissors'];
choices['paper'].beats = choices['rock'];
choices['scissors'].beats = choices['paper'];

var playerChoice = choices['rock'];
var cpuChoice = choices['paper'];

if(playerChoice.beats === cpuChoice) {
    //winner!
} else if(playerChoice === cpuChoice) {
    //tie
} else {
    //loser
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the global variables `p1Choice` and `cChoice` are never getting set by the `rockSelected`, `paperSelected`, `scissorSelected`, and `cpuSelect` methods. The reason behind it is that these function definitions have a parameter that has the same name as your global variables. So what is actually happening is that you are only changing the local variable's value, which is not your intent.

For instance, in the `rockSelected` method, since the function definition includes the `p1Choice` parameter, the expression `p1Choice = "R"` only sets the local variable, leaving the global variable undefined.

Now when you call the `compare` method it will always return the same value because your global variables are still undefined.

To fix this problem, you can just get rid of the parameters for the `rockSelected`, `paperSelected`, `scissorSelected`, and `cpuSelect` methods. This should make it so the global variables are actually getting set, which will then make your `compare` method work correctly. For example, the `rockSelected` method should look like this:

```
function rockSelected() {
    p1Choice = "R";
    alert (p1Choice);
}
```

You will also have to get rid of the two parameters in the `compare` method so it uses the global variables there as well.

Also, if you are interested, this bug is called "variable shadowing" and you can get some basic information about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing). Basically, the lesson to be learned here is to be conscious of your variable names in regards to their scope.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code, to stick to the original purpose of the question. The issue is that you were not using the functions you created. I removed the 3 functions you made to use as image buttons since they didn't reference any HTML and you didn't provide any HTML as well as the variables you weren't using. I'm sure you can modify the code to be more efficient. [Here](http://labs.codecademy.com/CrPr/1#:workspace) is a working example of your modified code.

```
function cpuSelect () {
    cChoice = Math.random();
    if (cChoice <= 0.33) {
        cChoice = "R";
    alert ("CPU Selected Rock");
    return cChoice;
    }
    else if (cChoice >= 0.34  && cChoice <= 0.66)
    {cChoice = "P";
   alert ("CPU Selected Paper");
    return cChoice;
    }
    else 
    {cChoice = "S";
   alert ("CPU Selected Scissors");
    return cChoice;
    }
}

//check user imput against computer selection
function  compare (p1Choice) {
    cChoice = cpuSelect();

    if (p1Choice == "R") {
        if (cChoice == "R") {
            alert ("player chose rock, cpu chose rock - it was a tie");
            return "it was a tie";
        }
        else if (cChoice == "P") {
            alert ("player chose rock, cpu chose paper - Paper wins!");
            return "paper wins";
        }
        else {
            alert ("player chose rock, cpu chose scissors - rock wins");
            return "rock wins";
        }
    }
    else if (p1Choice == "P") {
        if (cChoice == "R") {
            alert ("player chose paper, cpu chose rock - paper wins");
            return "paper wins";
        } else if (cChoice == "P") {
            alert ("player chose paper, cpu chose paper - it was a tie");
            return "it was a tie";
        } else {
            alert ("player chose paper, cpu chose scissors -scissors wins");
            return "scissors wins";
        }
    }
    else {
        if (cChoice == "R") {
        alert ("player chose scissors, cpu chose rock - rock wins");
        return "rock wins";
        } else if (cChoice == "P") {
            alert ("player chose scissors, cpu chose paper - scissors wins");
            return "scissors wins";
        } else {
            alert ("player chose scissors, cpu chose scissors - it was a tie");
            return "it was a tie";
        }
    }
}

compare("R");
```

Comment: Thank everyone for your responses.  I  was able to get it to work by removing the parameters being passed from each function.  I apologize for leaving off my html code....I was trying to streamline my question.

Comment: Great, make sure to up vote helpful answers and choose an answer if it was helpful. Otherwise, add your own answer if none of these was helpful - it could potentially help someone else in the future.